# What does clear(Filename) do in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

```
files=dir('*.cpp');
for i=1:length(files)
    Filename=files(i).name;
    clear(Filename); 
    ......
end
```

Could anybody explain what does clear(Filename) do? I think it does not delete the variable Filename because I still see that variable at the workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear(str)` will clear the variable whose name is given by the string in `str`. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html):

> `clear('name1','name2','name3',...)` is the function form of the syntax. Use this form for variable names and function names stored in strings.

So in your case, it is clearing the variable whose name is the string in `files(i).name`.

#### Example:

```
>> a=1:10;
>> str='a';

%#check what variables are in the workspace
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x10               80  double              
  str       1x1                 2  char                

>> clear(str)

%#check again
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  str       1x1                 2  char
```

Comment: Note also that A) clear clears more than just variables, it is used to unload functions, so if files(i).name were "foo.m", clear would unload foo.m; and B) if clear doesn't find anything with the specified name, it silently returns.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearing the variable files(i).name, where files(i).name is evaluated to the name of the filname

Let's say you had a variable called 'test.cpp', and a filename called 'test.cpp'
This would clear the variable 'test.cpp' from your workspace